# Using ddSlick and selecting an item in the list by value rather than index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ddSlick to change my drop down menus into prettier ones;

http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

But I have a problem. I rely on programatically changing the selected item in a list, but I must do it by value rather than index. So this is the code to select the list item by index;

```
$('#demoSetSelected').ddslick('select', {index: 1 });
```

I can't seem to find any way of doing it in the documentation, thought there may be someone who has come across and solved the issue. Or if anyway knows an alternative plugin that does the same job as ddSlick?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and the workaround was ugly - basically, I had to loop through all the items that ddslick was holding, match the value, and get the index from there.  I think I got source of [their demo page](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) to help me understand examples 3 and 4.  I used example 3 to help me understand how to go through all of its data, so I could loop through the items, find a matching value, and grab its index.  Then example 4 let me set the dropdown item.  Sorry, I can't find the files I tested with.

DdSlick looked decent, but in the end, I went with [MsDropDown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown).  I found it more robust - and it helped that it had a SetIndexByValue function.  They have detailed documentation on their github site as well as on their demo site.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to select ddslick dropdown programatically.

Pass selected:true in your json data you need to appear selected

```
var ddData = [
    {
        text: "Facebook",
        value: 1,
        selected: false,
        description: "Description with Facebook",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/facebook-icon-32.png"
    },
    {
        text: "Twitter",
        value: 2,
        selected: true,
        description: "Description with Twitter",
        imageSrc: "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/Images/twitter-icon-32.png"
    }
];
```

I hope you understand the point that the place where you create your json data just put the condition(something like if the id from the database matches to the id in the data you created for plugin) make selected:true else selected:false
The above code will make twitter selected by default.

Hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I see this option in [Github](https://github.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/issues/14):

```
$('#myDropdown li:has(.dd-option-text:contains("MyValue"))').index();
```

or if text is not equal to value:

```
 $('#myDropdown li:has(input[value="MyValue"])').index();
```

Comment: Can one maybe do an equals on the `dd-option-text` rather that contains? in the case where one have 3 values where the one keyword exists in more than one option: `Elected`, `Not Elected`, `May Be Elected`? In this case, the contains returns the last option with `Elected` which is not correct. Cannot use the value - it must be text in this case?

Answer (score 1):

ugly but works:

```
            var s = 0;
            var ind;
            $('#your_select .dd-option-value').each(function(i) {
                if ($(this).val() == your_value_to_test) {
                    ind = s;
                    return false;
                }
                s++;
            });

            $('#your_select').ddslick('select', {index: ind });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also force the selected option before formating your drop down list
before calling .ddslick() just select an option in your select like this

```
    $("#demoSetSelected  option[value='YOURVALUE']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

and then :

```
    $("#demoSetSelected").dsslick();
```